# Why is cURL reporting an invalid IP address as an error?

Tags: php, curl, dns

I have the following PHP code that uses cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31.json");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$a_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

echo curl_error($ch);
```

I then get the following error when I try to access the page over HTTP:

> Failed to connect to 0.0.0.31: Invalid argument

However, the code works fine when run from the command line.

What could *possible* cause cURL to try to connect to 0.0.0.31, which is AFAIK, not even a valid IP address?

Comment: I assume you've checked that DNS resolution is working properly. Does cURL work correctly from the command line?

Comment: @Tim: Yup. Works fine from the command line of the same server.

Comment: Hmm. Very strange. See my question/suggestion below.

Comment: Where are you testing your code? At work? Maybe proxy server @work denies access to unknown hosts? Otherwise your dns is I guess wrong(maybe hacked!!). Try to flush your dns cache??

Comment: Could it be that something is mis-interpreting the `/` characters in the URL as `.` , turning the URL into `0.0.0.31`? The fact that both end in `31` is curious. I've never seen something like that happen before, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What could possible cause cURL to try to connect to 0.0.0.31, which is AFAIK, not even a valid IP address?"

Your DNS is botched. I tested your code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the code works fine when run from the command line," do you mean you have run it with the PHP CLI interpreter? If that's the case, you might check for any noticeable mismatches between the output of `php -i` vs. `phpinfo()` on the web server. It might be some strange version mismatch or environment problem, although your guess is as good as mine.

If you are (as I had originally thought) just talking about running the `curl` command, you could try checking version numbers or environment variables there too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I think what you might have done was to construct the url like so:

```
$url = "http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/" + 31 + ".json";
```

And for some reason the url then is translated to 0.0.0.31.

Instead try to concatinate the string, like so:

```
$url = "http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/" . 31 . ".json";
```

Solved my issue at least!